# Ilasm.exe missing after repair of .net

Tags: .net, ilasm

I have repaired .net 4.0 but (still) cannot find:

Ilasm.exe

Any ideas? I need it to do this:

[strong name signing of assembly](http://buffered.io/posts/net-fu-signing-an-unsigned-assembly-without-delay-signing/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should exist in your Windows folder, under `Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319`.

That being said, it also comes with Visual Studio or the [Windows SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279).  This has the advantage of also installing command prompts which setup the environment correctly, and can make this simpler to use.

For details, see [the documentation for Ilasm.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/496e4ekx%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Nope, you are thinking of ildasm. ilasm has always been there along with the csc and vbc :)

Comment: I could mistaken too. It is just interesting that it installs itself under the windows framework directory if it does not come with the framework.

Comment: I just checked in the .NET 4 install files. ilasm.exe is indeed there. Both x86 and amd64 versions.

Answer (score 1):

It only comes with the full profile. Not the client profile.

Did you download the correct version?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by full profile? Thanks.